# Implement custom java barrier

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to implement a custom java barrier. I don't want to use the [CyclicBarrier class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

So all threads meet at a common point. The threads only procceed if all threads arrived at the barrier.

I want to use the wait/notify/notifyAll methods to implement the barrier.

So this is what I came up with

```
public class Barrier{

    private final int threadNumber;

    public Barrier(int pThreadNumber){
        this.threadNumber = pThreadNumber;
    }

    public synchronized void barrier(){
        wait();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseBarrier(){
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseThread(){
        notify();
    }
}
```

But I don't really understand how to achieve that a certain number of threads are stopped until all threads arrived. Is it possible to implement a barrier using only wait/notify/notify all?

Comment: Is this homework? Or why don't you want to use a CyclicBarrier?

Comment: I just try to get into java threads and concurrency and this sounds to be an interesting exercise to learn from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of homework, so I am only giving a hint:

You want all threads to proceed when `threadNumber` threads are waiting. That's equivalent to the first `threadNumber - 1` threads waiting for the `threadNumber`-th thread to arrive. One way is to count the number of threads, and do something special once the `threadNumber`-th thread arrives.

Answer (score 0):

An additional hint that is related to a Java detail: a thread that is blocked on a `wait()` can be woken up spuriously; see the [Object.wait() javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).

To tolerate spurious wakeups, you need to have a `while` loop where simple logic demands only an `if` check or a blind `wait()`.